# Json Post to another view

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am a beginner in Jquery and don't know much. So I am trying to post some data to the controller and then access them and pass them to another view. Here's the case. I have a Model named Booking:

```
   [Key]
    public int ID { set; get; }
    public int memberID { get; set; }

    public DateTime departureDate { set; get; }
    public DateTime returnDate { set; get; }

   [ForeignKey("memberID")]
   public virtual Flight flight { get; set; }
   [ForeignKey("memberID")]
   public virtual Memeber member { get; set; }
```

Here's the jquery code from booking view:

```
$('#panel').on('click', 'a.btn', function () {          
        var booking = {
            destination: blah...,
            departureDate: $('#arrivalDate').val(),
            returnDate: $('#departureDate').val()
    };
        var dataToPost = JSON.stringify(booking);

        $.ajax(
            {
                type: "POST", //HTTP POST Method
                url: "Booking/GetData", // Controller/View 
                data: dataToPost,
                datatype: 'json',
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"
            });
    });
```

And then in the View Model I want to get from the guest user just the dates and the destination and offer him a select button, which after the user click it, it post the info to a method in the controller and then use this controller to send the gathered data to another view where I ask the user to enter his credentials, say member first name and then save it to DB. I researched it and I have seen only the cases where Json post all the attributes of the object to the method which takes as parameter that Object class. Don't know to deal with either part so any detailed help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Some of the properties in the data you're sending (`destination` and `checkedIn`) do not exist in your `Booking` class

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan You're right, but I removed some of the attributes just to keep it simple here. The idea is that I am not getting all the attributes from this view. I am getting just a couple which I want to send to another view in order to ask the user for the other attributes.

Comment: Do not use ajax. Send the data via normal form submit and in your server action method (which handles the form submit) ,pass it to the next view.

Comment: The whole point of ajax is to stay on the **same** page! No not use ajax if you want to redirect to another view.

Comment: @Shyju How can I do that since I get the departure and return dates from the html part and then in the jquery script I get the flight in the required dates. So I have no idea how to come around with that. I know that AJAX is not the right thing to do. I want to get all three values of dates and flight and pass it to the controller where can I assign send them in another view where I can enter the rest of details for the member and then add the complete object to the database with all the attributes.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Yes, i realized that but how an i post them to the controller and send them to another view?

Comment: Create a view model with properties needed for the view (If you need the user to enter  2 dates and 2 place name, create a flat view model with those 4 properties and use that for your view and your HttpPost action method. As long as you have input elements for the properties of your view model inside the form, when the form is submitted, your http post action method parameter will be populated.by model binder

Comment: But using a normal form and submit button, and then a `return RedirectToAction(...)` in the POST method.

Comment: @Shyju I do have a model view for the Booking and the Member. Do you mean creating another one just for that view?

Comment: yes.View models are specific to that view.

Comment: @Shyju The other thing is that I can access the dates with Html.BeginForm() ,but I am not sure about the flights since I am getting them in the jquery

Comment: You can always set your input elements using jQuery. For example (`$("#YourFlightInputElementId").val("Detroit");`